# Extract data from Object Array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

this is about image to text (OCR) converter using terrasect. Refering to a working codepen demo at [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/poZLrRm?editors=1010), I managed to extract the text using data.text in my code. May I ask how to extract the **numbers (Highlighted in Green)** which is 936 and 385 in my case? I have tried using data.html but does not work.

I will aprreciate any help I can get. You will have to upload an image with words for it to work since it is an OCR Reader.

Image with text:
https://i.ibb.co/gZLWbjC/dog.jpg

[image]

```
function result(data){
  var r = $(".result");
 console.log(data);
  r.append(
    "<div class='sixteen wide column output'>success" +
    "<div class='ui message'><pre>" + data.text +"</pre></div>" + 
    "</div>"
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use regex to match it if possible

Comment: @Justinas, hi, I am unsure how to do that :)

Comment: I see that there are many occurrences of  `bbox 0 0 {greenNumbers}`, do you only desire the first occurrence?

Comment: @Damzaky, hi, yes, the first occurence, bbox 0 0 936 385;, how do i extract the numbers from the html as text? I used data.html to extract the html as text in the console. I have added a text example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DOMParser` to parse the HTML and then get the `page_1` element and then get its title. After that, you could parse the title to get the numbers by selecting the numbers between `bbox`  and `;`, then you could take the third and fourth number.

Modify the `function result(data)` to this:

```
function result(data){
  var r = $(".result");
 
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const parsed = parser.parseFromString(data.html, 'text/html');
  const firstOccurrence = parsed.getElementById('page_1').getAttribute('title');
  const numbers = firstOccurrence.split('bbox ')[1].split(';')[0].split(' ');

  console.log("green numbers:", numbers[2], numbers[3])
  
  r.append(
    "<div class='sixteen wide column output'>success" +
    "<div class='ui message'><pre>" + data.text +"</pre></div>" + 
    "</div>"
  );
}
```

Here is the [working fork codepen](https://codepen.io/damzaky/pen/MWBXoPQ).